# Polyspace alerts about use of system-defined parameter flags for system functions

Tags: c, static-analysis, misra

I am working with Polyspace Code Prover and Bug Finder to perform the static analysis of my Linux application written in C.

We are getting several alerts regarding the use of flags as defined by the "man" pages of said calls. In the man pages of functions like open(), write() or syslog(), we can see that they have a parameter which we can pass as an OR of several flags defined by the interface, like in the following example:

```
fd_value = shm_open(shm_key, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL , S_IRWXU);
```

Polyspace complains that, in the example above, the flags `O_CREAT`, `O_RDWR` and `O_EXCL` are of different essential types (some unsigned, some signed), and thus such an OR operation is not recommended. This is true according to MISRA's 10.1 guideline, but if that's how the system defines its API and its values what can I do about it? Seems to me like casting the values just to make the tool happy is risky.

Is there any other way around the problem besides justifying those violations?

Thank you, best regards!

Comment: What happens if you "cheat" by casts? E.g. `shm_open(shm_key, (int)((unsigned)(O_CREAT) | (unsigned)(O_RDWR) | (unsigned)(O_EXCL)), S_IRWXU);`. I guess, these functions/values were defined at a time where the differences between `int` and `unsigned` in bit arithmetics were not considered that hard. ;-)

Comment: I don't think Linux and MISRA-C will come to love each other much. Essentially you are asking: why is `shm_open` written like crap? Good question. It takes some considerable obfuscation skill to get different signedness of those enums, particularly since standard C demands that enumeration constants are of type `int` and the function takes `int` as parameter.

Comment: That's not quite what I am asking, what I am asking is: if shm_open just happens to be written like that, do I "cheat" to comply with the tool or do I use the interface as I'm told and justify that the violation is not because of my code, but because that's just how the interface I'm given is written.

Comment: @Scheff I think we tested something like that and it seemed like it worked, but my question is more on the lines of: is that really the way to go or are we hiding potential errors and incompatibilities with an external interface just to get cleaner reports? In my opinion, I'd personally use the interface and the defined values as they are and specify/justify somewhere else that this interface is non-compliant, but since my project manager is wary of putting too many justifications (to her credit, with good criteria), I wanted to know if there are alternatives to either approach. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeJuanTorresQuiroga For "hardcore" MISRA-C implementations, you don't allow any C code in the project not to follow MISRA-C, including libraries. For "MISRA-C light", you can make exceptions. Mostly it depends on if the application is actually a mission-critical one, or if you are just using MISRA-C as a bug-killing standard to improve quality. In case of the former, the answer is simply: this library cannot be used for this application, because it is sloppily written.

Comment: My project is a demonstrator with no criticality requirements of that kind, we are just using MISRA-C as part of our internal quality procedure. Therefore, I think we will just blame it on the library and be done with it. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeJuanTorresQuiroga Yeah in that case a deviation from the rule is probably the best way to go, for the use of this specific function.

Comment: The standard libraries are full of poor code, that "works" - but is not as "correct" as it could be.  MISRA Compliance tries to help with **adopted code** but until the Standard defines things "correctly" we all have these sort of issues :(

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat strange that those values are defined with different signess. It may be a good idea to add a platform isolation layer that will redefine those constants into module-specific constants performing necessary casts and probably dealing with cross-platform differences.

```
typedef int t_my_shm_open_flags;

#if(defined(PLATFORM1))
#define MY_SHM_OPEN_FLAG_CREATE     ((t_my_shm_open_flags) O_CREAT)
#define MY_SHM_OPEN_FLAG_READ_WRITE ((t_my_shm_open_flags) O_RDWR)
#define MY_SHM_OPEN_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE  ((t_my_shm_open_flags) O_EXCL)
#else
/* error for unsupported platform */
#endif

#define MY_SHM_OPEN_DEFAULT_FLAGS (MY_SHM_OPEN_FLAG_CREATE | MY_SHM_OPEN_FLAG_READ_WRITE | MY_SHM_OPEN_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Comment: The cause is most likely a design flaw in the library code. We shouldn't need to produce dirty hacks to use a function as intended.